# Betrieve access to data without DDF

Tags: sql, pervasive, qbasic, btrieve

I would need help to access data from Betrieve files.

Persasive ODBC driver need a DDF file that define the "schema" for each table, my problem is that DDF file not exist.

The QBasic code that I should migrate to C#, make a substring functions and "cast" for every data type. If I can undestand the syntax, I could create the needed files.

I had used the DDF Builder of PSQLv11, but the aplication send an error "Invalid collating sequence"

Someone can upload an example with BTR and DDF files to know if it works with ODBC?

Here is the code and DB: http://www.mediafire.com/?mnvfa1tg1d6y64w

Answer (score 1):

I realize this post is nearly five years old, but I thought I'd contribute in case someone else comes across this in a search.  Any application written in QBasic would not likely be using Pervasive SQL but rather an older version of Windows Btrieve, or even more likely DOS Btrieve.  Pervasive stopped selling and supporting the version that is probably required for the application in question a long time ago, specifically 6.15 for Windows.  I believe the last version for DOS was 5.10a. Both used (optionally) DDF files, specifically FILE.DDF, FIELD.DDF, and INDEX.DDF.  Anything created with Pervasive's SQL version of their DDF manager would not likely be backwards compatible and might not even be able to read the Btrieve Data.  This question might have received better attention had it been tagged for Btrieve.